# Wordpress testsite redirecting to HTTPS automatically

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

I have installed an SSL certificate on my live site to make the site secure. Now I've backuped the site to my non-secure test environment but while loading, the testsite keeps redirecting to HTTPS.

I've changed the .htacces to what I've typed below but the site keeps redirecting to HTTPS. Does anyone know how to fix this??  Thanks in advance!!

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    RewriteBase /speelgoedfeestje/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /speelgoedfeestje/index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: may be your test environment is the subdirectory of main domain

Comment: I've changed all the url references with the Search Replace DB tool.

Comment: can you please show me your live url and test url so i can make a idea

Comment: live: www.speelgoedfeestje.nl  test: www.kendmedia.nl/speelgoedfeestje

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the actual website URL in WordPress to not include https?

Comment: yes, I first used 'Search Replace DB', after that I have exported the sql, changed manually all the HTTPS references to HTTP, and then imported the sql. So I think that must do that job?